# token authentication - Enable or Disable anonymous authentication

Tags: authentication, iis, token, openid-connect, anonymous

When setting up token authentication it always recommends to enable anonymous authentication, and disable all others.

I found today that even if I disable anonymous authentication the token is still validated by my server. I would have thought that would have blocked all access to the server.

Should anonymous authentication be enabled or disabled when using token authentication. Can you also explain the reason

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

when you disable the anonymous authentication no one can access your site even authenticated users can not able to access it. enable anonymous authentication allow authenticated users to access the site.

Comment: I am finding that when I disable all types of authentication, when I send a request using token authentication, it actually hits my server. So your answer is fine, but it does not explain how setting it to disabled does this.

Comment: @rideintothesun could you please share your web.config file?